# How to prevent automated request to the server?

Tags: performance, server, architecture, request, load-balancing

How to prevent automated request? This is not a duplicate question. The existing answers are not compromised.

What if an attacker using a program which make 1 Million requests per minute? Or the program may use various proxy or vpn and can request millions of request to the server. The server will slow down due to the heavy load. How can this be prevented?

Can IP Tables handle millions of request per second?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent someone from attacking you. You simply have to deal with it.

You either spin up enough server capacity to handle the brute force attack, or if you don't want your servers to have to handle the load then you have to deal with the attack closer to the edge of the network instead.

Have a look at the following:

https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/ddos-mitigation/

https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/glossary/ddos-blackhole-routing/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDoS_mitigation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack